# Asymptotics of $\sum_{p\leq n} \frac{1}{p(p-1)}$

Tags: summation, prime-numbers, analytic-number-theory

Consider the sum $\sum\limits_{p\leq n} \frac{1}{p(p-1)}$, where $p$ are the primes.
This sum certainly converges to some value $<1$ (the sum over all integers is $1$).
**Is there a closed form of the limit?**
**Can it be computed easily (with enough precision)?**

Also, **is there an asymptotic formula of the sum depending on $n$**?
One approach would be the following
$$
\sum\limits_{p\leq n} \frac{1}{p(p-1)} = \sum\limits_{p\leq n} \frac{1}{p-1} - \frac{1}{p}
$$

The latter has an asymptotic expansion of $\log\log(n) + M$ where M is the [Meissel-Mertens constant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meissel%E2%80%93Mertens_constant).

I am not sure about the expansion of the former, it is probably along the lines of $\log\log(n) + M'$ with $M'$ the appropriate constant.

I am not sure if there is another closed form for $M'$ (except for $M'=M+\sum\frac{1}{p(p-1)})$, nor if $M,M'$ can be efficiently computed.

Comment: There is no closed-form for the limit. It should follow from Mertens theorem and a partial summation that the asymptotic of $\sum_{p\ge n} \frac1{p(p-1)}$ is $\sum_{m\ge n}\frac1{m(m-1)\log m}$. You can write the limit as $\sum_{l\ge 2} c_l \log \zeta(l+2)$ which eventually provides a faster algorithm  than Erathostene, due to the exponential decay of $\log \zeta(l+2)$ and the rapid algorithms for evaluating $\log$ and $\zeta(s)$.

Comment: If you sum the terms up to $p$, then the sum of the remaining terms is going to be less than about $1/(p \log p)$.  So yes, it's certainly possible to compute this with any desired precision.

Comment: Is it feasible to compute it to 1000 bits of precision? Certainly going through the first $2^{1000}$ summands is out of the question.

Comment: Lots of information, including the first ten thousand decimal digits, at https://oeis.org/A136141

Comment: Have you looked at that link, Kolja?

Comment: Yes, I have, in particular I found the [HIGH PRECISION COMPUTATION OF
HARDY-LITTLEWOOD CONSTANTS](https://oeis.org/A221712/a221712.pdf) of Cohen very useful. Thanks !

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is easy to see that
$$
\sum\limits_p {\frac{1}{{p(p - 1)}}}  = \sum\limits_{k = 2}^\infty  {P(k)}  = \sum\limits_{n = 1}^\infty  {\frac{{\mu (n)}}{n}\left( {\sum\limits_{k = 2}^\infty  {\log \zeta (nk)} } \right)} ,
$$
where $P$ is the prime zeta function, $\zeta$ is the Riemann zeta function, and $\mu$ is the Möbius function. Then
\begin{align*}
\sum\limits_{n = 1}^\infty  {\frac{{\mu (n)}}{n}\left( {\sum\limits_{k = 2}^\infty  {\log \zeta (nk)} } \right)}  = \;& \sum\limits_{n = 1}^N {\frac{{\mu (n)}}{n}\left( {\sum\limits_{k = 2}^{\left\lceil {N/n} \right\rceil  + 1} {\log \zeta (nk)} } \right)} \\ & + \sum\limits_{n = N + 1}^\infty  {\frac{{\mu (n)}}{n}\left( {\sum\limits_{k = 2}^\infty  {\log \zeta (nk)} } \right)}  \\ &+ \sum\limits_{n = 1}^N {\frac{{\mu (n)}}{n}\left( {\sum\limits_{k = \left\lceil {N/n} \right\rceil  + 2}^\infty  {\log \zeta (nk)} } \right)} 
\end{align*}
for any $N\geq 1$. Now
$$
\log \zeta (nk) \le 2 \cdot \frac{1}{{2^{nk} }}
$$
for any $n\ge 1$ and $k\ge 2$. Thus for any $n\ge 1$ and $M\ge 1$,
$$
\sum\limits_{k = M + 1}^\infty  {\log \zeta (nk)}  \le 2 \cdot \sum\limits_{k = M + 1}^\infty  {\frac{1}{{2^{nk} }}}  = 2^{1 - nM} .
$$
Therefore
$$
\left| {\sum\limits_{n = N + 1}^\infty  {\frac{{\mu (n)}}{n}\left( {\sum\limits_{k = 2}^\infty  {\log \zeta (nk)} } \right)} } \right| \le 2\sum\limits_{n = N + 1}^\infty  {\frac{1}{{n \cdot 2^n }}}  \le 2\int_N^{ + \infty } {\frac{{{\rm d}t}}{{t \cdot 2^t }}}  \le \frac{2}{{\log 2}}\frac{1}{{N \cdot 2^N }}
$$
and
$$
\left| {\sum\limits_{n = 1}^N {\frac{{\mu (n)}}{n}\left( {\sum\limits_{k = \left\lceil {N/n} \right\rceil  + 2}^\infty  {\log \zeta (nk)} } \right)} } \right| \le 2\sum\limits_{n = 1}^\infty  {\frac{1}{{n \cdot 2^{n\left\lceil {N/n} \right\rceil  + n} }}}  \le 2\frac{1}{{2^N }}\sum\limits_{n = 1}^\infty  {\frac{1}{{n \cdot 2^n }}}  = \frac{{2\log 2}}{{2^N }}
$$
for any $N\ge 1$. Accordingly,
$$
\sum\limits_p {\frac{1}{{p(p - 1)}}}  = \sum\limits_{n = 1}^N {\frac{{\mu (n)}}{n}\left( {\sum\limits_{k = 2}^{\left\lceil {N/n} \right\rceil  + 1} {\log \zeta (nk)} } \right)}  + R_N ,
$$
for any $N\ge 1$, where
$$
\left| {R_N } \right| \le \frac{2}{{\log 2}}\frac{1}{{N \cdot 2^N }} + \frac{{2\log 2}}{{2^N }} < \frac{5}{{2^N }}.
$$
With $N=3400$, I got
\begin{align*}& 0.77315666904979512786436745985594239561874133608318604831100606735670\\&
9028489233397833798758823320818328937814256148184877115780660449046900\\&
2378832590763500601782383946617309470017305607667464101342674273541621\\&
9952460707589642449366317124379893255273683122617198789965614988900346\\&
8789581761777440507530380403930615725533887927380132834996433277138637\\&
7049479823191921992768751966642321281245994223008799785641115700164415\\&
4003845978165611336094017461569027505458605345995912204829815522858359\\&
0259088070578636499788833417902629524916542777136670298457774510084876\\&
5454067301120053261899310892066356658770246502596716068326040486612803\\&
6312902391262059228007144014989942678635902481893404222498689320321229\\&
1181268463226742700101487927499658707519455860084392737464646754241323\\&
4741957037164652252932590566930054867393817757225596885032596671453783\\&
9155845083333132992637494356480167180297031616517608172434964548568691\\&
0734031704796454256219160251853205082189649435393816591198262102370390\\&
29428059110079374440938\ldots
\end{align*}
for the first $1000$ digits.

Comment: Great answer! Thanks!